# angularjs simple .then or $q service in async requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, q

I don't know what is the exactly difference between AngularJS `$q` service and simply using `.then()` after async request.

Simple example with `.then()` :

```
function InboxService($http) {
  this.getEmails = function getEmails() {
    return $http.get('/emails');
  };
}
```

And when using the service (just part of code):

```
InboxService.getEmails()
.then(function (response) {
  // use response
});
```

What is the difference with `$q` service **with resolve and reject** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference with $q service with resolve and reject ?

I assume you are asking about the usage of `var deferred = $q.defer()` with subsequent `deferred.resolve()` or `deferred.reject()`? In this case, the answer is that you don't need it since you already have a promise object returned by `$http` service. In fact, manually constructing another new promise with `$q` is not recommended and considered an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

In cases where you work with asynchronous functions (timeouts, ajax-requests) that are not already wrapped into promise, then this is a case when you might want to use `$q` to create and return promise. But once again, in your case you don't need it as `$http` service constructs promise for you and one more is simply redundant.

Comment: Thank you. And one more question, what is your suggestion for multiple async requests that should run into each other?

Comment: It is convenient to return one (which is a promise) from another, then outer promise will resolve with inner one. Like if f1 and f2 returns promises you could write `f1().then(function(data1) { return f2(data1) }).then(function(data2) { console.log(data2) })` or even `f1().then(f2).then(function(data2) { console.log(data2) })`.

Comment: Thank you. In these cases I can just access to one of the results. How can I chain the requests but access to each request's result?

Answer (score 1):

The $q is superfluous and in most cases is not needed.  http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/