# Angular $http with $ in a forEach loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that returns the below object

return {

```
 getCuisines: function(cuisineNames){
      if (typeof cuisineNames !== 'string' && typeof cuisineNames !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('Cusine type should be a string or should not have value');
      }
      cuisineNames = cuisineNames || options.term;
      cuisineNames = cuisineNames.split(',');


      var promises=[];
      cuisineNames.forEach(function(cuisine){
        var defered = $q.defer();
        options.term =  cuisine + ' '+ 'food';
        $http.get(url,{params: options}).success(function(data){
          defered.resolve(data);
          localStorageService.setDishes(cuisine,data.businesses);
          console.log("Cuisine ="+cuisine);

          console.log(data);
        });
        promises.push(defered.promise);
      });
      return $q.all(promises);
    }
  };
```

I call this factory from a controller using

```
MyFactory.getCuisines('American,Indian,Italian,Mexican,Japanese,Korean').then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
```

When the application is executed. I get all cuisines as korean. which the last parameter passed.

UPDATE 1:

I updated my code to below code. Removed $q. pushed $http to promises array still not working. same response. I checked my server all calls made to server are for Korean food.

```
return {
  getCuisines: function(cuisineNames){
      if (typeof cuisineNames !== 'string' && typeof cuisineNames !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('Cusine type should be a string or should not have value');
      }

      cuisineNames = cuisineNames || options.term;
      cuisineNames = cuisineNames.split(',');


      var promises=[];
      cuisineNames.forEach(function(cuisine){
        options.term =  cuisine + ' '+ 'food';
        console.log(options.term);  //I see different cuisine name here
        promises.push($http.get(url,{params: options}).success(function(data){
          localStorageService.setDishes(cuisine,data.businesses);
               console.log(data);
        }));
      });
      return $q.all(promises);
    }
  };
```

Comment: First of all, why do you use `$q` service for `$http` serivce?? http service returns a promise as default. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631601/angularjs-simple-then-or-q-service-in-async-requests

Comment: be careful, there can be only 6 ajax calls at the same time (navigator limitation). You should better use 1 call to get all the results.

Answer (score 1):

You get only Korean because is the last on in the iteration and overrides the other promises. You want to `push` to promises the `$http.get` requests and not the deferrer you define for catching the `$http` result.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. As @topless has mentioned, you would need to push $http promise to
   your promises array
2. $q.all() should have success method '.then' to capture
   the results from your service calls, check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises) for example

Answer (score 0):

Hum, difficult without seeing the network activity, but you are not returning from the get $http call, try with that syntax:

```
getCuisines: function(cuisineNames){
    if (typeof cuisineNames !== 'string' && typeof cuisineNames !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('Cusine type should be a string or should not have value');
    }

    cuisineNames = cuisineNames || options.term;
    cuisineNames = cuisineNames.split(',');

    var promises = cuisineNames.map(function(cuisine) {
        options.term =  cuisine + ' '+ 'food';
        console.log(options.term);
        return $http.get(url,{params: options})
                    .then(function(data){
                        localStorageService.setDishes(cuisine,data.businesses);
                        console.log(data);
                        return data;
                    });
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: I think '.then' / '.success' depends on the version of angular one is using. I tried your solution with both cases I am getting same response. `console.log(options.term);` logs different cuisine name but call is made for only korean