# (Angular http$): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I am working on an apps to read JSON file.

Currently I am able to retrieve and read the JSON file but the problem is when to choose data in JSON.

Error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Below is my code.

Services.js

```
.factory("mainData", function($http, $log, $q) {
    var chartData;

    return {

        all: function() {
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/aZolla/getGlazCharts.do'})
                    .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                         d.resolve(data);
                        })
                    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                        $log.warn(data, status, header, config);
            });

            chartData = d.promise;

            return d.promise;     
        },

       get: function(chartID) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        if (chartData[i].id === parseInt(chartID)) {
          return chartData[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
 };
});
```

Controller.js

```
.controller("ChartsListsCtrl", function($scope, mainData) {

    mainData.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.chartLists = data;
    }            
   )

.controller('ChartsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, mainData) {

  $scope.chart = mainData.get($stateParams.chartId);

})
```

Comment: You load both controllers simultaniously? This looks like an asyncronic problem.

Comment: Check whether the chartData contains expected data during the execution  of get function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `chartData` to your get function. Try this:

```
get: function(chartID, chartData) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    if (chartData[i].id === parseInt(chartID)) {
      return chartData[i];
  }
}
```

In controller:

```
.controller('ChartsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, mainData) {
  mainData.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.chart = mainData.get($stateParams.chartId, data);
  });
})
```

Comment: Glad to help you. And be careful about working with `$q` service. You shouldn't use `$q` service in `$http` request. Because http request returns promise by itself. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631601/angularjs-simple-then-or-q-service-in-async-requests

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
.controller("ChartsListsCtrl", function($scope, mainData) {

    mainData.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.chartLists = data;
    }            
   )

   .controller('ChartsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, mainData) {
      mainData.all().then(function(data){
       $scope.chart = mainData.get($stateParams.chartId);
      })
   })
```

You need to load `all` before `get` call. In your first controller `all` call being happened. But it does not mean in your second controller it will be available, because your second controller may be initialized same time with your first controller and till then may be your `all` call is not getting finished.